# Iterating through multiple lists in Django templates

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

views.py

```
def exa(request):
    list1 = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
    list2 = [1, 5, 7]
    list3 = [True, False, False]
   context = {
        'l1' : list1,
        'l2' : list2,
        'l3' : list3,
    }
    return render(request, 'patient_registration/111.html', context)
```

template

```
{%for a, b in zip(l1, l2)%}
  {{a}}
  {{b}}
{%endfor%}
```

template can be not show any list

i want to display multipe list thorugh context in template

Comment: How would you expect the result to be displayed in the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` in your view:

```
mylist = zip(list1, list2, list3)
context = {
    'mylist': mylist
}
```

and in your template use:

```
{% for item1, item2, item3 in mylist %}
```

to iterate through your lists.

Comment: i tried it but didn't work